# Issues Writing to an excel 2007 binary file in C#

Tags: c#, excel

I am currently seeing an issue with export results from a gridview to an excel file. We used the .xls version and while it opens, we were seeing some users waiting 1hr to open an exported file of about 80000 rows and about 50MB. During this 1hr period, they can't use any MS Office programs. Note this file is also formatted.

One way i have read to get around this is to use the .xlsb format. While i tested it by saving the 50MB file and saw a significant file size reduction, i am having an issue opening the file after writing it as a .xlsb file.

I get the error saying `"****Excel cannot open the file 'testme.xlsb' because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file.**"**`

Here's the code i use. Can you please help?

```
try
        {

            HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName + ".xlsb");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.binary.macroEnabled.12"; 
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter tw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
            ctrl.RenderControl(tw);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(sw.ToString());
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Let me guess: RenderControl is rendering HTML...try to inspect it with Notepad. There I don't see any code that creates/put an Excel file in response stream. To read as: RenderControl() of a GridView will not **export** anything, it'll render control itself as HTML.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out exactly where the content of your xlsb file is being generated....if you're storing it to a byte array, you could  get rid of your string writer, and html writer, and just do a binary write for your byte array, then close out the response.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti yes, we are rendering html. ctrl is a gridView and we are exporting the content as formatted into the excel file

Comment: @user2366842 content of the xlsb file is the content of the gridView.

Comment: There I don't see any exporting, you're streaming HTML into response and it's what browser will download. Try to rename downloaded file as .html and open it in a browser. It's not a xlsb file, it's just plain text HTML and Excel complains about that.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti you are correct. So the reason why that approach was taken is that we need to be able to write details of a grid as formatted into an excel file. We are currently streaming html into a .xls file but we are running into size and performance issues. When i saved the file as xls on my local and created a copy saving it as .xlsb, it was way smaller. Hence, why i was trying xlsb plus from my understanding, its the 2007 equivalent of .xls (both binary)

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Do you have any suggestions or perhaps a better approach that currently implemented to getting it done. I am think perhaps using the applicable microsoft excel library in C# but that's way too much effort and load than we have time for

Answer (score -1):

Dumping HTML in a file and calling it Excel works for as long it works - seems like you've hit the limit.

Loop over the actual rows and use a library to write a proper Excel file and you'll be good to go.